# transition timing function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

First problem it's doesn't work `transition timing function`(always work as `transition timing function: linear`,
second problem I wanna set up two setting for `transition timing function`

1. Setting in case reducing window size `easy out`
2. Setting in case increasing window size 'linear`

Any how fix it?

```css
/*====== Ignore section __start ======*/

* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

section {
  display: table-cell;
}
/*====== Ignore section __end ======*/


aside {
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -15px 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, .5);

  /*__transition*/
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 2s;
}

/*====== Ignore section __start ======*/
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  display: table-row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/*====== Ignore section __end ======*/

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  aside {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    font-size: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <main>
      <section>SECTION</section>
      <aside>ASIDE</aside>
    </main>
    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I mean "Any idea" instead "Any"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding `transition-timing-function` value with the `transition` shorthand.

Either merge the two together:

```
aside {
    ...
    transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
```

Or change the order of your declarations:

```
aside {
    ...
    transition: all 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First issue is that you're overriding the timing function when you place the transition property below it. Try this:

```
opacity: 1;
transition: all 2s;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
```

As far as using different transition timing function based on wether window is growing or shrinking, I do not believe that is possible in just CSS. You would likely need to write an event handler for window which captures that then add a class to  which your CSS can use to know if window is shrinking or growing.